# Input tag type time to get value in 12-hour format in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an ASP Textbox with TextMode time:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Time" ID="time_box" runat="server">
```

When I run the code in the browser, I can input the time in 12-hour format.
But when I click the submit button, the value in the database is stored in 24-hour format.

I also tried to do a JavaScript "alert" to see if the time is in 12-hours or not, but I still got the value in 24-hours.

So, how do I save the time in 12-hour format in the database?

I am using:

```
time_box.Text
time_box.TextWithLiterals //or should I use this?
```

Or do I need to convert the time into 12-hours in the back-end C# code?

Comment: Time value does not have a format internally. Format is only used when entering/displaying time value. So, what is exactly the problem, where do you want to display 12-hour format instead of 24-hour?

Comment: When you load time from database, what is the data type of the value? Is it `TimeSpan` or `DateTime`?

Comment: @Dusan I think it is DateTime, I didn't develop the database, but If I wanted to save only the "time" which datatype should be used for that?

Comment: If the `value` is between 0 and 24 hours (which is almost always the case), then the proper data type for the SQL Server is `time(7)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of `format` when storing date, time, double, ... values in your database. For example, the `date` in SQL Server is always stored as a numeric value which makes arithmetic and comparisons much simpler and faster. But, for example, when this value is displayed to you in SSMS, you don't see the raw number but the human readable string like 17-12-2014.

The `format` usually exists in concept of displaying/parsing some value in representation that needs to be human readable.

When you load value from database and it is of `TimeSpan` data type, then use this code to display that value in 12-hour format:

```
time_box.Text = new DateTime(timeValue.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

If the loaded value is of `DateTime` type, then use this code:

```
time_box.Text = timeValue.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```